# Sympy symbolic function composition

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to figure out symbolic function composition with `sympy`. I came up with this and it works when `n` is an integer, but it fails when `n` is a `Symbol`.

```
# f o f o f ... o f(s), n f usages
def compose_self_n(u, s, n):
    c = s
    for _ in range(n):
        c = u.subs(s, c)
    return c
```

This works:

```
class TestCompositeFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_compose(self):
        x = symbols('x')
        f = x / 5
        n = 3

        composition = compose_self_n(f, x, n)

        self.assertEqual(composition.subs(x, 1).evalf(), 1/125)
```

But this fails with a maximum recursion depth error:

```
class TestCompositeFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_compose(self):
        x = symbols('x')
        f = x / 5
        n = symbols('n')

        # Create a composition of f with itself n times
        composition = compose_self_n(f, x, n)
```

How should I approach it so that function composition works symbolically? I understand that `range` expects an integer but I don't know how to go about it the `sympy` way. I also tried with recursion instead of a for loop.

Eventually my goal is to define various symbolic compositions and test them like this: `self.assertTrue(simplify(left - right) == 0)`

Thank you!

Comment: To do this you would have to write your own function class and define how it should print, etc.. Look at something like `Factorial` to see how it is written. There is not function in SymPy to represent the composition of a function (as far as I know).